# iPhone Programming: Send a text message? Access contact list?

Tags: iphone

I'm still new to the API and I wanted to ask:

- Can you send a text message programmatically?
- Can you access the users contact list programmatically?

I'm thinking **no**.  I haven't seen anything about text messaging in the API, and I figure the sandboxing that the iPhone does keeps you away from the phones contact list.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You'd think that if it was possible SOMEONE would have written an app to combine contact list entries by now.  At this point that's the biggest complaint about my phone.  I don't even have a 3G, but this bothers me more than anything a 3G "fixes" (including memory!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) I'm afraid you can't send SMS with the iPhone SDK although you can make a link to send an SMS like so:

```
a href="sms:408-555-5555"&gt;408 555 5555&lt;/a&gt;
```

2) You can access the contact list with the [Address Book UI framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html)

Comment: You can also programmatically open the Text (SMS) by passing a sms:// URL to UIApplication's openURL method.

Answer (score 1):

one way round the sms/mms problem is to use an external aggregator then you can utilise http between a server and the iphone to send sms obviously there is a cost involved this way to the developer

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can build an app to send SMS.
All u need a server API, which u gonna call through ur code, to send sms.
I am saying this bcoz i am currently working on it.

As soon as i m done with my app,i am gonna share it.
http://shishir.com?from=shishir&to=shishir&message=hi&sandbox=false&username=user&password=pass

u hv to pass values through URL.

will go in deep very soon.

regards
shishir